# ckeditor disallow some tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and so far like it. Since I am loading it from the CDN I don't have immediate access to config.js.  I want to allow most of the html tags but want to block  tabs as my page formatting heavily depends on the div tags. However I am not able to block div tags from the CKEditor. I read the ckeditor documentation and followed CKEDITOR.replace and replaceall methods with textareas and the textareas classed as ckeditor. However my changes don't seem to take any effect.

```
I am loading the ckeditor.js from a CDN first.

Then I tried 
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {
    allowedContent: 'a[!href]; ul; li{text-align}(someclass)'
} );
```

I placed the above function both in document.ready and also near the end of the body after the said textarea is loaded at different times, between script tags, to test.

Somehow my changes dont seem to have any effect. Does anyone have any suggestions or help? Obviously I am screwing it up somewhere. Any guidance on where to put the CKEDITOR.replace/replaceall calls? My textarea is classed as ckeditor.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My textarea is classed as ckeditor.

CKEditor automatically replaces all `textarea` of `.ckeditor` class in DOM. This is the first reason why your explicit `CKEDITOR.replace` call does nothing. Another reason is that such invocation [expects `id` to be passed](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) as a first argument.

If you want to leave it this way, move `allowedContent` definition to [`config.js`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-3) so it's shared among instances and avoid `CKEDITOR.replace`. Otherwise, get rid of `.ckeditor` class from your element or disable/change [`config.replaceClass`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-replaceClass) to make `CKEDITOR.replace` work as expected (`id` as a parameter).

P.S. Make sure you have the latest version of CKEditor.

Comment: Hi Oleq. I can add an ID to the textarea I want to manipulate. Trouble with config.js I have is that I am loading ckeditor from a CDN and hence does not have the ckeditor loading from my site. Can I still load a local config.js to modify the ckeditor loaded from online?  I can certainly remove the ckeditor class from the textarea and instead give it an id and then replace.

Comment: Tried that. Added xeditor class to text editor and removed the ckeditor class, now when I open the page, it does show on mouseover the xeditor - so it is getting activated. However it still does not stop me from using all the tags. What am I goofing up!

Comment: Doesn't really solve the issue, because even if the `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', config);` is used, the ACF doesn't kick in and you can input pretty much anything. I tried making the toolbar into a source button only and the allowedContent into just "p" but I could input anything into source mode and it didn't care when swithing to wysiwyg.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using CKEditor 4.1 or newer? Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/JLFRM/). It works like a charm with CDN.

Comment: Had been away for a bit. Yes it worked like a charm indeed. I was loading 4.02. i changed it to the one you put in the fiddle. Worked - now to look at all the tags I want to allow ...   Thanks a lot.